# This small TikZ example does not work because of "x axis={include value=0}"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Here is a small example of TikZ plotting:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes, all axes={length=3cm},
visualize as line,x axis={include value=0}]
data {
x, y
1, 1
2, 4
3, 2
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It does not work because of the tikz axis option

```
x axis={include value=0}
```

The error is:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/data visualization/axis
options/include value' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

If i remove it, it compiles fine.

This option appears on page 561 of the following tikz pgf manual:
http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf

I have texlive-pgfplots-svn31822.1.9-5.fc20.noarch installed.

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You're using an outdated version of pgfplots (from Texlive 2013 packaged by Fedora) and probably something else too. Update and it will work.

Comment: data visualization has nothing to do with pgfplots. But it seems that your TikZ version is off. Upgrade it to v3.00

Comment: I upgraded to version 3.0.0 and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem fixed by updating a package (see comments).